# SSRS 2008 Employee Card or Product Card

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a 12 "Product Card" in one "A4 Portrait" Page. I am using SSRS "Sql Server Reporting Service" 2008, and I have tried this solution " http://forums.asp.net/t/1373432.aspx " but no use. Please help me to get results like the photo below :
http://www.4shared.com/photo/mbiPfhC1/Problem.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you storing your images at DB level, if so what format are they saved in?

Comment: the images not in DB level, but what is the relation between the image format and my question???

Answer (score 2):

1. Create main report with a tablix. In tablix include a row group and use rectangle for fields.
2. Nest sub-report in rectangles.
3. Use tablix with column group in the sub-report.
4. Tune layout of main report for A4 and tune layout of sub-report for part of A4 sheet.